# Java Swing Animations

Tags: java, swing, animation

I have to do Java Project about elevator management system.

My problem is in 2 `JPanel`'s. First is for `JLabel`'s and `Button`'s, one for each floor - I use layout because i want it to be responsive. Before program start I have dialog which I can set first and last floor level. Here's code:

```
public void setFloors() {
    floorNavigation = new JPanel();
    floorNavigation.setLayout(new BoxLayout(floorNavigation, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    floorNavigation.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    for(JPanel p : floorPanels){
        floorNavigation.add(p);
    }
    floorNavigation.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    frame.add(floorNavigation, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
}

public void createFloorPanel() {
    JPanel floorPanel;
    for(JLabel l : floorLabels){
        floorPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        floorPanel.add(l);
        floorPanel.add(floorButtons.get(floorLabels.indexOf(l)));
        floorPanels.add(floorPanel);
    }
}
```

I want to make a elevator move animation to Y of each `JLabel` in the other `JPanel`. Any ideas how to do that? Things like `getY()` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly both the panel that contains the buttons and the panel that contains the animation are going to be positioned side by side, and thus going to have the same height. In this situation you can calculate the Y coordinate positions simply by knowing the current height of the panel and the number of buttons you have. Simply divide the height with number of buttons and multiply by number of floors you want to reach (note that this will give you the floors in reverse order, top down).

After you calculate those positions you can use simple linear animation to move your "elevator" (I am guessing an imported icon or image) to the corresponding positions of the buttons. Here is a simple template for the animation (the small circle represents your elevator image):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SimpleAnimation {

  static int x;
  static int y = 150;
  static int floor_distance = 130;
  static int animation_speed = 10; //less is faster
  static MyDrawPanel panel = new MyDrawPanel();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JButton buttonUp = new JButton("Floor Up");
    final JButton buttonDown = new JButton("Floor Down");

    buttonUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      (new AnimatorUp()).execute();
      }
    });

    buttonDown.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      (new AnimatorDown()).execute();
      }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, buttonUp);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonDown);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  static class AnimatorUp extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
      try {
        x = (int)(panel.getWidth() / 2);
        for(int i = 0; i < floor_distance; i++) {
          y--;
          panel.repaint();
          try{ Thread.sleep(animation_speed); } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
      } catch (Exception ignore) {
      }
      return "";
    }
  }

  static class AnimatorDown extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
      try {
        x = (int)(panel.getWidth() / 2);
        for(int i = 0; i < floor_distance; i++) {
          y++;
          panel.repaint();
          try{ Thread.sleep(animation_speed); } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
      } catch (Exception ignore) {
      }
      return "";
    }
  }

  static class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
      g.setColor(new Color(215,215,215));
      x = (int)(panel.getWidth() / 2);
      g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
  }

}
```

You can modify this code so the buttons trigger the animation which moves the "elevator" to a specific floor. By calculating the difference between current Y position of the "elevator" and the Y position of wanted floor, you can set the direction and range of animation to execute.